# How to get the SHA1 for the tip of a branch origin? (without having to switch to it)

Tags: git, branch

How can the SHA1 for the tip of origin be accessed?

For example the local branch may be behind from not being current when `git pull` runs, or it may not even be checked out.

---

*To give some context, I'm looking to print a log of commits that doesn't depend on the state of my local branches.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking at a branch off the origin called `<branch>`, then you could use `git rev-parse origin/<branch>` to get you the sha for the head of the branch.